# Response cache issue in Wso2 Api Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am facing an issue while configuring Response cache.

I have configured response cache at my local system by using the following link ***https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+Caching***. But when i hit an API request from rest client it is still sending request to the backend server (legacy app).
I am using WSO2 API Manager 2.x

Thanks 
Raju K

Comment: Enable wire logs and send the same request twice. Then post wire logs here.
http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Make sure you enabled `Response Caching` in publisher UI for that particular API. To confirm it's done correctly, have a look at API synapse file in `repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/`. It should have cache mediator like this.

```
     <cache scope="per-host"
            collector="false"
            hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator"
            timeout="300">
        <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
     </cache>
```

Comment: Thank you Bhathiya

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code in api_home\repository\resources\api_templates\velocity_template.xml

now it's working fine.

Comment: <cache timeout="$!responseCacheTimeOut" scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.DOMHASHGenerator">
     <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
</cache>

Comment: i suppose it should be gateway component?